# Angular 2 - TCP Connection

Tags: angular, tcp, socket.io

I'm trying to make a tcp connection from Angular 11.2.5 to a local device (physical, hardware) that only accepts TCP connections via IP.

When I use the `net` package in Node, I can make a successful TCP connection to the device. Since that package is not available in Ng, I tried using the `socket.io-client v4.0.1` package for Ng, but cannot get it to work.

Here's my test connection code for `socket.io-client`, which does NOT work:

```
const {io} = require('socket.io-client');
const ip_address = '127.0.0.1';
const port = '5555';
const socket = io(`${ip_address}:${port}`);
socket.connect();

socket.on('connect', () => {
    console.log('connected');
    console.log(socket.connected, socket.id);
});

// also tried the below, did not connect as well
const socket = io.connect(`${ip_address}:${port}`);
```

There are no error messages in the console

How can I make a TCP connection in Angular ?

Comment: can anybody confirm whether tcp calls can be made from Ng ?

Comment: try the rxjs socket

Comment: @RobinDijkhof: did not get rxjs websocket to work either

Comment: are there any error messages in the console?

Comment: i doubt browser would allow establishing anything other than HTTP/Websocket - my guess it's sandboxed for security reasons

Comment: @DavidB.no, there are no error messages in the console

Comment: can you provide a stackblitz?

Comment: @AakashGarg: cannot create a TCP server in Stackblitz, and regarding code see the code snippet from the OP. You need a tcp server (or device accepting tcp connections) to test that code.

Comment: Using rxjs, are there any errors in the subscriber?

Comment: @RobinDijkhof:
there are not, but maybe I'm using it incorrectly for the TCP connection. Could you post an example that I can follow so I can report back ? Thanks.

Comment: I am sure there are enough examples

Comment: @RobinDijkhof post it as answer so I can follow your steps and accept the post, if it works. I was following the general examples that were posted.

Comment: Hi Pete, I have added a) config checks/helper b) samples and c) some links to full apps that work for me on angular 11

Comment: Define 'does not work'.

Comment: @user207421 the response from the device is not being received in Ng socket-io

Answer (score 2):

**Update**: sorry I missed the HW device on the end... short answer is, the browser ***CAN NOT directly connect to a hard device socket***. So, as a workaround **you NEED another software or bridge to mediate the data between the browser and the hardware device as below...**

---

The issue is that its a `websocket` "framed" *data* on the client browser is not understood by your device socket, and you need to overcome/ "bridge" or "proxy" that connection over to the device.

You have to overcome the websocket using something like [Websockify](https://github.com/novnc/websockify)/socket.io server  as a proxy to bridge between a websocket client and a non-websocket server.

```
So, the clients webscoket doesn't communicate with the device directly, but with a websockify server instead.

Subsequently websockify unpacks/unwraps the framed data from the Websocket data stream and forwards it to your device. Viceversa - the response from the device is packed into WebSocket frames forwarded to client.
```

---

Please post Both `Client` & `Server Code` & Console, it would help us debug easier.

Install packages, `CLI` like so

```
npm install socket.io-client
npm install @types/socket.io-client
```

Then import the libs

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import * as io from 'socket.io-client';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import * as Rx from 'rxjs/Rx';
import { environment } from '../environments/environment';
```

---

Check client config / setup

```
let hostname = window.location.hostname;
// you can change the undefined below to server if its not your local
let url = ( hostname === 'localhost' ) ? `${window.location.protocol}//${hostname}:8080` : undefined;
const config: SocketIoConfig = { url: url, options: {} };
```

Check Server config

```
const port = process.env.PORT || 8080;
const server = http.Server(app);
const io = require( 'socket.io' )( server );
server.listen( port, () => { console.log( `listening on port: ${port}`) } );
```

---

Then use a service with `observers` to handle the messages sent and received easily nice sample [here](https://github.com/luixaviles/socket-io-typescript-chat/)  …

```
@Injectable()
export class WebsocketService {

  // Our socket connection
  private socket;

  constructor() { }

  connect(): Rx.Subject<MessageEvent> {
    // If don't use environment variables, you can hard code `environment.ws_url` as `http://localhost:5000`
    this.socket = io(environment.ws_url);

    // Observable to observe incoming messages from server socket.io server.
    let observable = new Observable(observer => {
        this.socket.on('message', (data) => {
          console.log("Received message from backend Websocket Server")
          observer.next(data);
        })
        return () => {
          this.socket.disconnect();
        }
    });

    // Observer listens to messages, other client components and send messages back to our socket server using `next()`
    let observer = {
        next: (data: Object) => {
            this.socket.emit('message', JSON.stringify(data));
        },
    };

    // return a Rx.Subject its a combination of observer and observable.
    return Rx.Subject.create(observer, observable);
  }

}
```

Comment: thank you, will test this soon, but want to point out, as per the OP, that the TCP connection needs to be made to a physical hardware device that accepts TCP requests on it's IP (once it is on the local network). This device is NOT running socket.io server, hence I cannot post 'server side' code. The TCP connection to the device does work in Node via 'net' package. Will report back, thanks.

Comment: I think I understand, issue is that this is a web socket.. and you need to bridge it over..

Comment: ok, there is a JS version of websockify, but the main question is: will this work in Ng without having to go through Node ? If it does, can you update your post to reflect the Ng set up for websockify in addition to your socket-io code ?

Comment: if this is working for you please mark as answer / upvote

Comment: it's not working as I'm looking for a solution that works in Ng only, it seems your updated answer requires an additional  proxy that runs outside of Ng...  unless I'm mistaken ?

Comment: @pete19 You can't connect to TCP straight from the browser so you will need a back-end  for your app that will handle communication between it and the device.