# Create TCP connection in Angular12

Tags: angular, ip-address, tcpclient

Is it possible to connect to server using TCP IP protocol in Angular 12?
I need to send data to server and get corresponding response.

I am relatively new to Angular and trying to find, How to connect to server using TCP IP and port number, get the connection status and send data to the server.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Angular 2 - TCP Connection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67069381/angular-2-tcp-connection)

Comment: I don't have server access, I need to implement on client side only

Comment: Well then...the answer is no...you cannot :)

Comment: The browsers generally don't support this - this is one of the reasons why web sockets were introduced.